# Using Images uploaded in google drive in Colab

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, image-classification, pytorch, colab

Does anyone know how to use already uploaded images in Google Drive to colaboratory for creating a trainloader? 
I'm creating the trainloader and model in Pytorch

Comment: Refer this [blog](https://link.medium.com/g7snWZVia4).

Comment: Thank you! Issue resolved.